# How to use a different theme for a contribution page using Drupal

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, 4.7, theme

The ability to use a mobile friendly theme for a contribution page is vital these days.  I used 'Themekey CiviCRM' along with Themekey which worked for a while but doesn't anymore. Fixing that would be good but it seems a bit of a cludge. Isn't there a better solution for this common requirement? Or should I be using a webform rather than the contribution page?  I'm using 'Seven' as the normal theme for the back office functions, and don't want to use a different theme for ALL public pages as then CiviVolunteer pages are themed differently. On 4.7.24 and Drupal.

Comment: "but doesn't anymore"? any idea what changed? as far as i know themekey still works for this task

Comment: I had this working a few weeks ago & now it stopped working. The 'only' change that happened in that period was the domain was moved to a different server in the same hosting company.  But everything works OK (except no ImageMagick - separate problem!).  However I uninstalled & reinstalled 'Themekey CiviCRM' but to no effect. Suggestions welcome! By the way, when I said 'cludge' above that was not meant to sound negative - I was trying to make the point that this feature should work out of the (underfunded) box!  Andy

Comment: Got Themekey CiviCRM working again - had to go into Themekey settings, Compatability, then check ' CiviCRM Theme (Define alternate themes for CiviCRM.)'.  I didn't do this before so don't know how this got unchecked. Grrr!

Comment: glad it is sorted

Comment: Kind of time waster to find out after the last comment that you found the answer yourself. May be you should answer the question yourself so that it appears as answered?

Comment: Answer posted, you are right - sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Themekey does indeed support this, as long as you are using Drupal.  I couldn't get this to work until I found that as well as creating a record of the page and the theme you want to use, you have to do a bit more.  You must have 'Themekey CiviCRM Integration' installed and you have to first go to Configuration/Themekey/Settings/Compatability then check 'CiviCRM Theme (Define alternate themes for CiviCRM.)'  See also my comments.